# vscode jupyter notebook error Error: Session cannot generate requests

Tags: jupyter-notebook, vscode-extensions

Error message in vs code when using jupyter extension connected to remote server using ssh.

> Error: Session cannot generate requests 
> Error: Session cannot generate requests 
> at w.executeCodeCell (/root/.vscode-server/extensions/ms-toolsai.jupyter-2021.8.1236758218/out/client/extension.js:90:327199)
> at w.execute (/root/.vscode-server/extensions/ms-toolsai.jupyter-2021.8.1236758218/out/client/extension.js:90:326520)
> at w.start (/root/.vscode-server/extensions/ms-toolsai.jupyter-2021.8.1236758218/out/client/extension.js:90:322336)
> at async t.CellExecutionQueue.executeQueuedCells (/root/.vscode-server/extensions/ms-toolsai.jupyter-2021.8.1236758218/out/client/extension.js:90:336863)
> at async t.CellExecutionQueue.start (/root/.vscode-server/extensions/ms-toolsai.jupyter-2021.8.1236758218/out/client/extension.js:90:336403)

I got this error after running the code below.

`import pandas as pd`
`from itertools import product`
`pd.DataFrame(product(item_table, user_table), columns = ['item_id', 'user_id'])`

- product function outputs all combinations of the given tables.
- item_table has 39729 number of items(39729 by 1)
- user_table has 251350 users(251350 by 1).

And the above code outputs 251350 x 39729 combination table.

Therefore I guess this is because of the large computation but I want to know the meaning of error messages and want to know how to solve the problem.

Comment: Hi, I am facing the same problem and I haven't managed to solve it. Did you find any solutions by any chance?

Comment: Hi, no:( I just modified the code to treat small data

Comment: Hello. This is what I did as well, I broke my dataset into 8 parts :( Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 0):

I have encountered the same problem (so so).
It happened when I tried to import tensorflow.keras.

I was no longer able to import packages.

I just changed of conda environment, and then got back to the one I was working in and it worked (but trying to import keras still caused the same problem).